# How to count the length of concatenated strings from one column based on an ID in another?

Tags: r, matrix, concatenation

I have the following function

```
set.seed(1984)
test <- function(paths){
  x <- matrix(rep(NA, paths*3), ncol = 3, 
              dimnames = list(c(), c("Cookie", "Site", "Count")))
  for(i in 1:paths){
    x[i, 1] <- round(sqrt(rnorm(1,50,100)^2))
    n <- function(){sample(1:10, size = 1)}
    draws <- function(){sample(LETTERS[1:5], n(), replace = T)}
    x[i, 2] <- paste(draws(), collapse = '-')
    }
  return(x)
}
```

Which produces output like

```
Cookie      Site                  Count
[1,] "91"   "B-D-E-A"             NA   
[2,] "37"   "E-A-D"               NA   
[3,] "108"  "B"                   NA   
[4,] "93"   "D-A-D"               NA   
[5,] "157"  "E-C"                 NA   
[6,] "52"   "B-C-D-A-C-C-B-A-B-E" NA
```

For each of the unique cookie IDs in the `Cookie` column I'd like to

1. concatenate each of its `Site` strings together (`Cookie` contains repeat values)
2. get that concatenation's length
3. drop that TOTAL length as the `Count` value for that `Cookie` ID (so, there may be repeats)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `data.table`, we can do

```
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(test(91))[, Count := as.character(sum(nchar(gsub("-", "", Site)))) , 
                    by = Cookie][]

dt[, Full_path := gsub("-", ", ", toString(Site)), by = Cookie]
head(dt)
#   Cookie          Site Count                    Full_path
#1:    258             A     1                            A
#2:     26     D-D-E-E-C    10 D, D, E, E, C, E, E, A, C, A
#3:     43         D-D-A     3                      D, D, A
#4:    171 C-C-E-A-B-D-E     7          C, C, E, A, B, D, E
#5:     57       A-D-D-C     4                   A, D, D, C
#6:    156           A-D     2                         A, D
```

If we need full-dashes

```
dt[, Full_path := paste(Site, collapse="-"), by = Cookie]
```

Comment: Any way to get it not to count the dashes?  I know that's a pain, but I need to retain the dashes in the object for some d3.js I have

Comment: @D8Amonk  Updated the ppost

Comment: Sorry for the follow-on, but if I wanted to mutate out a column with the full concatenation of the Site pieces? I've tried (within mutate) Full_Path = paste(Site, collapse = '-') but it's not working...

Comment: @D8Amonk  If it is by 'Cookie', try the updated code

Comment: how do i collapse that comma in the middle of Full_path?

Comment: @D8Amonk, Do you want something like `B,D,E,A,E,A,D` instead of `B-D-E-A,E-A-D`?

Comment: I'd like to have all dashes in the `Full_path` variable, like `B-D-E-A-E-A-D`

Answer (score 1):

This will group your matrix by the `Cookie` and return the total number of characters in the `Site` column (which is equal to the length of the concantenation.

```
test.df <- test(91)
library(dplyr)
test.df %>% 
  as.data.frame(., stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>% 
  group_by(Cookie) %>% 
  mutate(Count = sum(nchar(Site)))
```

If you want the `Count` to exclude the character `-`, just replace `Site` with `gsub("-", "", Site, fixed = TRUE)`.

Comment: Any way to get it not to count the dashes?  I know that's a pain, but I need to retain the dashes in the object for some d3.js I have

Comment: Sorry for the follow-on, but if I wanted to mutate out a column with the full concatenation of the `Site` pieces? I've tried (within mutate) `Full_Path = paste(Site, collapse = '-')` but it's not working...

Comment: Check out strsplit

Comment: when I wrap Site in strsplit (`strsplit(Site)`) inside the mutate and run `test(100)` it says it can't find Site